# Is there an efficient methodology for organizing an inherited project?

Tags: methodology

I think this is one of the things that has happened to everybody at some point in their careers.  I inherited a project that has software and hardware components as well as documentation responsibilities that ultimately fall to me.
Since I'm more managing the project components than running the team, I can't really implement agile or anything else that I've heard of.  There is seemingly as much new information coming in as I am already trying to organize and lend some structure to, so I can't get ahead far enough to rein in anything.

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to PM:SE. This site deals with questions that have canonical answers and unfortunately, as far as I can understand, yours is likely to be closed as being "Opinion Based". You might want to check the site tour here, which provides information on what makes a "good" question: http://pm.stackexchange.com/tour. There may be a good question here, on rescuing a project under pressure or dealing with the overload of information when becoming a new PM, but the question needs to be edited considerably to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

1. Identify deliverables
2. Identify workstreams to create deliverables
3. Identify teams to involve in workstreams
4. Identify tasks for teams

Please clarify what you mean by:

> has software and hardware components as well as documentation responsibilities that ultimately fall to me.